# Exception: Bluetooth Device is not ready

Tags: java, linux, bluetooth, bluecove

My java application makes a bluetooth server and waits for connection.My program works fine in windows.
but when I try to run it in Linux it gives this error.How can I resolve this?

```
BlueCove version 2.1.1-SNAPSHOT on bluez
javax.bluetooth.BluetoothStateException: Bluetooth Device is not ready. [1] Operation not permitted
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackBlueZ.nativeSetLocalDeviceDiscoverable(Native Method)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackBlueZ.setLocalDeviceDiscoverable(BluetoothStackBlueZ.java:307)
    at javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice.setDiscoverable(LocalDevice.java:206)
    at bluetoothjava.WaitThread.waitForConnection(WaitThread.java:32)
    at bluetoothjava.WaitThread.run(WaitThread.java:18)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
BlueCove stack shutdown completed
```

Comment: What do you get when you, just experimentally, comment out the setDiscoverable? maybe you will run into this: https://askubuntu.com/q/1273074/778232